# VB.NET set Categories / FlagIcon does not update email set the application Outlook2016

Tags: vb.net, outlook, categories

Here is the code I have

```
    Do While Read All eMails 
      If oMsg.Unread = vbTrue and 
         oMsg.Categories = Outlook.OlCategoryColor.olCategoryColorNone
         .
         .Prep the email 
         .
         Send the Prep'd email via SMTP
         oMsg.Categories = Outlook.OlCategoryColor.olCategoryColorGreen
      Else
         If oMsg.Unread = vbTrue and oMsg.Categories = oMsg.Categories =  Outlook.OlCategoryColor.olCategoryColorGreen
            oMsg.Unread = False
            Move from Inbox to another folder
         End If
      End If
    End Do
```

The Categories is not getting set to Green. If I go back to Outlook on my system I don't see that the Flag is set or turned on.

So when the program runs again the process enters the first If and sends the email again.

Outlook on my system, is NOT set in cached mode with Outlook365.

Even if I set Outlook in cached mode the Categories is still not set.

```
If you are wondering why I am doing the Send and Move in 2 step because with Outlook in non cached mode takes longer time to process. So I want all the emails to go out first and then move it out of inbox.
```

Any reason when set programmatically why the Categories is not set in Outlook.

Temporarily to resolve this I have a code

```
      If oMsg.Unread = vbTrue
         .
         .Prep the email 
         .
         Send the Prep'd email via SMTP
         oMsg.Unread = vbfalse
      Else
         If oMsg.Unread = vbfalse 
            Move from Inbox to another folder
         End If
      End If
```

Works Great. Issue, couple of users have access to the Inbox and if they move the cursor the email is marked as read and in my next process will just move it to the "another folder"

So if I set the Category that will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the message after changing any of its properties (except for `Unread`):

```
oMsg.Categories = Outlook.OlCategoryColor.olCategoryColorGreen
oMsg.Save
```

Comment: Thank You Dimitry, Didn't have to use that, but will use that for another project.
One of the issue I occasionally have namely once a year is the Move from Inbox to Processed folder. Before moving I do an Unread of the email, can see it getting Unread and after the move command see the email is still in the Inbox. If I go and check the Processed folder the email is there. So it resides now in Inbox and the Processed folder. But now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you iterate over all items in the folder you can meet different kind of items - mail, appointment, note, document and etc. For that reason I'd suggest checking the item type, so you could be sure you are dealing with a `MailItem` instance, otherwise you may call properties and methods that may not exists on the processed item.

Second, typically you need to call the `Save` method to preserve your changes on the item:

```
Private Sub GetCategoryToMail(item as MailItem)
    Item.Categories = "some category"
    Item.Save
End Sub
```

Third, there is no need to iterate over all items in the folder and checking the `UnRead` property value. You can do everything in the single iteration by setting properties, sending an email and then moving the original one to another folder.

Fourth, iterating over all items in the folder is not really a good idea. You need to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class to deal only with items that correspond to your search criteria. For example, the following code shows how to use these methods to find all unread items in the folder:

```
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
' ...
Private Sub FindAllUnreadEmails(folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder)
    Dim searchCriteria As String = "[UnRead] = true"
    Dim strBuilder As StringBuilder = Nothing
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim mail As Outlook._MailItem = Nothing
    Dim folderItems As Outlook.Items = Nothing
    Dim resultItem As Object = Nothing
    Try
        If (folder.UnReadItemCount > 0) Then
            strBuilder = New StringBuilder()
            folderItems = folder.Items
            resultItem = folderItems.Find(searchCriteria)
            While Not IsNothing(resultItem)
                If (TypeOf (resultItem) Is Outlook._MailItem) Then
                    counter += 1
                    mail = resultItem
                    strBuilder.AppendLine("#" + counter.ToString() + _
                                          " - Subject: " + mail.Subject)
                End If
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(resultItem)
                resultItem = folderItems.FindNext()
            End While
            If Not IsNothing(strBuilder) Then
                Debug.WriteLine(strBuilder.ToString())
            End If
        Else
            Debug.WriteLine("There is no match in the " + _
                                   folder.Name + " folder.")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        If Not IsNothing(folderItems) Then
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folderItems)
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

Read more about these methods in the articles that I wrote for the technical blog:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Comment: Thank You Eugene. In my process I follow the FIFO method method to process the emails. Start from the first email received to the latest email. 

Dim oItems As Outlook.Items = oInboxFolder.Items
Dim i as interegr = 1
do while true 
     if i<=oitems.count
        exit do
     endif 
.
     oMsg = oItems.Item(i)

   < Here I am already checking for all the mail type as you 
    have mentioned and only process >

      If iTypeClass = Outlook.OlObjectClass.olMail Then
         -----
          -----

Comment: If email is Unread
                 Process the Email
                 Forward the email with processing data to my customer

                 At End of processing 
                        mark as Read
                         <b> Move to Processed folder </b>
                        
          else
              display an error message
              continue next email.
          endif
      else 
          <b> Move that email to the Customer Service inbox </b>
      endif
.
      i=i+1
enddo

Comment: The reason I put this query was because in some cases the "Move to the Processed folder" completed but the email still remained in the Inbox. After posting this query over the weekend still had the issue , come following week the Move to the Processed folder and Move to Customer Service happened as if nothing had happened.

What caused this not to "Move to the Processed folder" was not sure. This process has been running for couple of years but every year or two have this 5-8 days issue.

Once again Thank You for your help